# Checking speed when no Rigidbody is involved

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a camera that has a script to follow a player. When I add a Rigidbody it doesn't show the speed. I want to make my fov dependant on the speed. There is nothing else that I can copy the speed off. How do I access the speed in the script?

Comment: Can you provide the script to give more information?

Comment: I dont really have a clue where to start. I looked at some documents on the answers.unity site and found a page but don't have the skill to understand whats going on.

Comment: You can read the "speed" of a Rigidbody by looking at the Rigidbody's `rigidbody.velocity.magnitude`

Comment: Well if the camera has a script that makes it follow the player, then camera speed is either the same as  players' speed or at least is dependant on it. You can probably get the speed from that camera script. Maybe post that ( a script to follow a player) so that people can see if that's the case?

Comment: public class CameraBehind : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform playerTransform;
    public Vector3 offset;
    public GameObject player;

    public float SmoothSpeed = 0.0f;

    void LateUpdate () {
            if (player){
            transform.position = playerTransform.position + offset;
            }
    }

    
}

Comment: Why not just have the camera (or player, or whatever) calculate its own velocity? `Vector3 previousPos; Vector3 newPos; Vector3 velocity; void Start() {newPos = transform.position;} void Update() { previousPos = newPos; newPos = transform.position;  velocity = (newPos - previousPos) / Time.deltaTime;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speed is just distance over time. Store the last few positions of the camera and their time stamps. And then calculate average speed between these positions.

If you store few points it will be very accurate but prone to changing quickly. If you store many, the speed will change smoother but won’t be as accurate.